# Karate Automation: Is there any way we can set the Scenario name dynamically from a json file

Tags: karate

I am using a JSON file which act as a test case document for my API testing. The JSON contain Test Case ID, Test case Description, Header and Request body details, which should be the driving factor of Automation

Currently i am looping a feature over this json file to set different header and body validations. However it will be helpful if i can set the Scenario name from JSON file while its iterating

Something like
serverpost.feature

```
Feature:re-usable feature to publish data

Scenario: TC_NAME  # TC_NAME is avaliable in the JSON data passed to this feature. However, CURRENTLY ITS NOT TAKING THIS DATA FROM JSON FILE.

Given path TC_ID   # TC ID is taken from JSON
Given url 'http://myappurl.com:8080/mytestapp/Servers/Data/uploadServer/'
And request { some: '#(BODY)' }   # Request Body Details is taken from JSON
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

In my honest opinion, you are asking for a very un-necessary feature. Please refer to the demo examples, look for it in the documentation.

Specifically, look at this one: [`dynamic-params.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/search/dynamic-params.feature). There are multiple ways to create / use a data table. Instead of trying to maintain 2 files - think of Karate as being both - your data table AND the test execution. There is no need to complicate things further.

If you really really want to re-use some JSON lying around, it is up to you but you won't be able to update the scenario name, sorry. What I suggest is just use the `print` statement to dump the name to the log and it will appear in the HTML report (refer to the doc). Note that when calling a feature in a loop using a JSON array, the `call` argument is ALREADY included the report, so you may not need to do anything.

Just an observation - your questions seem to be very basic, do you mind reading the doc and the examples a bit more thoroughly, thanks.

Comment: Hi Peter, We are trying to migrate a QA automation suite written in Gauge framework to Karate. Since the team wanted minimal configuration changes, we created a migration util to migrate the CSV content to JSON format, which is supported by karate. Since each row of CSV is one test case, we would like to see the TC_NAME as the scenario name in Karate, by which we can attain a one to one mapping. Please let us know, if there is any way to set the data from json as the scenario name.

Comment: @Sundan ok here is a question for you. assuming you could set the scenario name, where will it help you at run-time ?

Comment: Currently In the cucumber reports, the report for a feature show only one scenario name, eventhough the feature test different header combinations. If the Scenario names are dynamically taken from Json file for each loop, then report shows the details of individual test cases that are executed against each test case ID.

Comment: @Sundan okay, here's the bad news - in the Cucumber life-cycle (which Karate uses) there is no way to edit / parameterize the scenario name once the feature starts executing (not surprising). how about this - instead of generating JSON, why don't you generate a very minimal Karate feature with multiple scenarios. have all the logic in the Background. each Scenario will just set the reference to the part of the JSON needed. hey I think this is a great idea. open an issue if you want to brainstorm more :)